# Javascript to pass value from server to client doesnt work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, hidden-field

I have a fileupload control and a button in a webform.When i click on the button after selecting fileupload,it should save the image and rename it with a GUID.

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = string.Empty;
    string filePath = string.Empty;
    string extension = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        //Check if Fileupload control has file in it
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            // Get selected image extension
            extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToLower();
            //Check image is of valid type or not
            if (extension == ".jpg" || extension == ".jpeg" || extension == ".png" || extension == ".gif" || extension == ".bmp")
            {
                //Cretae unique name for the file
                fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + extension;
                //Create path for the image to store
                HiddenField1.Value = fileName;
                filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), fileName);
                //Save image in folder
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);
                //Show the panel and load the uploaded image in image control.
                //pnlCrop.Visible = true;
        }
```

The above code works just fine,saves the image and passes the GUID to the hiddenfield.Now i want to pass the value of hiddenfield to a client side variable and then display it as an alert.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function showfilename() {       
        setTimeout(function () {
            var dpGUID = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value;
            alert(dpGUID);
        },3000)
    }
</script>
```

Reason for using timeout? Because i want to read value of hiddenfield after it has been assigned the value on button click.

Note:I am using two functions on Buttonclick.One on client side and other on server side as follows :

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" Text="Button" OnClientClick="showfilename()" />
```

Is it possible? If yes,what could be causing a problem?

Comment: Which is the problem? is it not displaying the filename?

Comment: It is not showing any alert message @EnriqueZavaleta

Comment: If you are using a serverside one than the page is going to submit so what would be the purpose of what you are trying to do? Shouldn't the serverside code set whatever you are trying to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a [RegisterClientScriptBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /*All your code here*/
    //instead of HiddenField1.Value = fileName; write the line below
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "callJsFunction", "alert('" + fileName + "');", true);
}
```

and now you can get rid of the  `OnClientClick="showfilename()` and the `HiddenField`